# HDFS Files as input to Spark Mllib

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

All the examples in the tutorial use files in LibSVM format as input to Spark Mllib.(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html)

data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')

But I have a file with millions of rows located on HDFS and want to give this as an input to Spark MLLib using PySpark and I do not want to convert it into libsvm format.

Can anyone please guide me how to do this?

Comment: What does the format look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you give an input an algorithm in MLLib, you create an rdd of a certain data Type (say LabeledPoint Or a vector.) MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile will convert your data into a labeledpoint RDD for you.

You can directly transform your data into whatever format the algorithm needs and then give the resultant RDD as an input to your MLLib algorithm.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Rishi with few additions to that -

LibSVM format represents a `org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint`, it contains a label and a feature vector. If you don't have data in LibSVM format then you can create that by building a dataframe having a column of type `LabeledPoint`.

```
val trainingData = spark.read.text (<path to data folder or file>)
val trainingLabelPoints = trainingData.map { row =>

//LabeledPoint(<Label as a Double>, Vectors.sparse(....) )
LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("column 1"), Vectors.sparse(row.getAs[Double]("column 2")...)
}.toDF("labelpoints")

//trainingLabelPoints can be used for input to a Mllib library
```

Clustering algorithms like K-mean don't need LabelPoints, just a Vector column is enough. 
Some classification algorithms like LinearSVN can take 2 columns - label and feature vector, a LabelPoint would work too. 
If you have words in training document then you can use org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec to convert words to vectors.

So you have quite a lot of choices.